# Can compromise mean danger?

Tags: meaning

https://wordpanda.net/definition/compromising

noun compromising

an endangering, especially of reputation; exposure to danger, suspicion, etc.: a compromise of one's integrity.

According to the above text, compromise can be a noun and mean danger. But I could not find that meaning in any famous dictionary. Due to I am not a native English speaker, probably I misunderstood the above text. So can compromise mean danger?

Comment: I think you are doing yourself a disservice by consulting only one dictionary. (If you did look in others, say what you found). If you did look in others, and did not find what you want, does that not tell you something? "Exposure to danger" is not the same as the danger itself.

Comment: Please include all relevant research, using multiple reliable dictionaries such as ODO, CED, Collins, AHD, M-W – all freely available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***[Compromise](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/compromising)*** , as a noun, according to Merriam-Webster, can mean:

> a concession to something derogatory or prejudicial

Making a concession in this context would mean surrendering, or giving up, part of one's integrity (e.g. their morals or ethics). Vocabulary.com states:

> Compromise can also mean to erode or diminish. If you never repair your brakes, you will compromise the safety of the car. If you cheat, you compromise your integrity.
>
> https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/compromise

Answer (score 1):

The OED shows it as sense 8, of the verb - *to compromise*.

> 8. ‘To put to the hazard of being censured’ (Phillips); to expose (oneself, one's own or another's reputation, credit, or interests) to
>      risk or danger, to imperil; to involve in a hazardous course, to
>      commit (oneself).
>
> 1696   E. Phillips New World of Words (new ed.) (at cited word)   It
>   behov'd him not to Compromise his Honour and his Reputation.
>
> 1727–31   in N. Bailey Universal Etymol. Eng. Dict. II.
>
> 1785   T. Jefferson Corr. in Wks. (1859) I. 436   I think..you by no
>   means compromised yourself or your country.
>
> 1795   W. Roscoe Life Lorenzo de' Medici (1836) vii. 232   An open
>   attack [by Politiano upon Merula] might therefore have compromised the
>   name of Lorenzo.
>
> 1810   T. Green Diary 29 Sept. 1796   Compromise..he [Roscoe] employs,
>   by what authority I know not, to express the putting to hazard by
>   implication.
>
> 1841–8   F. Myers Catholic Thoughts II. iii. §35   No essential of
>   Jewish faith would be compromised by doubting the Divine dictation of
>   the Proverbs of Agur.
>
> 1856   J. A. Froude Hist. Eng. I. 171   The characters of a king of
>   England, and of the three estates of the realm, are compromised in the
>   treatment which she received from them.
>
> 1883   J. A. Froude Short Stud. IV. i. vii. 76   Alexander..had no
>   intention of compromising himself by an authoritative decision.